# How to secure an oracle 12c standard edition database connection?

Tags: security, oracle12c

All of the information on Oracles website (that I've found so far) is for enterprise edition. How do I create a secure connection from an oracle client to a 12c DB in standard edition?
Thanks for the assist.

Comment: If you are asking for connection encryption, you can force your server to accept only encrypted client connections by setting `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=required` in your servers `SQLNET.ORA`. The default is `accepted` which would allow unencrypted connections, too. See the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF206)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSchaefers .   I'll bring this to the team's attention on Monday for review.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm not sure @MichaelSchaefers because my research indicates that it is part of the Oracle Advanced Security Option (PAS) option which is only available in Enterprise Edition Oracle.  I need to confirm we can use it in Standard Edition before I know if my problem is solved.  I will mark the question answered as soon as I can confirm it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force your server to accept only encrypted client connections by setting `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=required` in your servers `SQLNET.ORA`. The default is `accepted` which would allow unencrypted connections, too. See the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF206)

This feature is available for all licensed editions of all supported releases. Quote from [12c Database Licensing Information User Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#BABCDCDI), Section "Oracle Wallet":

> Strong authentication services (Kerberos, PKI, and RADIUS) and network
>   encryption (native network encryption and SSL/TLS) are no longer part
>   of Oracle Advanced Security and are available in all licensed editions
>   of all supported releases of the Oracle database.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSchaefers.  I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.